# Why listings' deletekeywords=[1]{foo} does delete foo keyword defined by morekeywords=[2]{foo}?

Tags: listings

In the following MWE, I define two `listings` languages (`bluelang` and `redlang`), each of them having a `foo` keyword but from different lists:

- number 1 for the former,
- number 2 for the latter.

The strange thing is, if at some point `foo` from list number 1 is deleted (with `\lstset{deletekeywords=[1]{foo}}`), `foo` from list number 2 is deleted as well: it is necessary to redefine `foo` from list number 2 (with `\lstset{morekeywords=[2]{foo}}`) to override this deletion.

Hence my question: why `deletekeywords=[1]{foo}` does delete `foo` keyword defined by `morekeywords=[2]{foo}`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstdefinelanguage{bluelang}{
  morekeywords=[1]{foo,bar}
}

\lstdefinelanguage{redlang}{
  morekeywords=[2]{foo,baz}
}%

\lstset{%
  alsolanguage=bluelang,
  alsolanguage=redlang,
  keywordstyle={[1]\color{blue}},
  keywordstyle={[2]\color{red}},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
foo bar baz
\end{lstlisting}
%
\lstset{deletekeywords=[1]{foo}}
%
\begin{lstlisting}
foo bar baz
\end{lstlisting}
%
\lstset{morekeywords=[2]{foo}}
%
\begin{lstlisting}
foo bar baz
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Suspicion: a keyword belongs to only one list; so once you remove it there is no *backup*.

Comment: @Symbol1 I guess you're right, indeed. A quick look at the `listings`' implementation (outch!) fails to make me have a strong opinion about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My comment was not correct. The truth, to the best of my knowledge, is that [listings](/questions/tagged/listings) will clean up its memory only when you enter `lstlisting` or `\lstinline`.

That is to say, you can play with `more` and `delete` like this:

```
\lstset{
    morekeywords=[4]{foo},
    morekeywords=[3]{foo},
    morekeywords=[2]{foo},
    morekeywords=[1]{foo}
}
\lstset{
    deletekeywords=[4]{foo}, % [4] deleted
    deletekeywords=[2]{foo}  % [2] deleted
}
\lstinline{foo} % [3] wins; [1] deleted automatically
```

Then [listings](/questions/tagged/listings) will assign `foo` to class 3 because it is the first class assignment that is not canceled. And then all data regarding class 1 will be erased automatically.

However, if you enter `\lstinline` at the middle then [listings](/questions/tagged/listings) will assign `bar` to class 1 and erase all data regarding class 3, 2, 1. Notice that at this point there is only one copy of `bar` in the memory. So later when you try to delete `bar` you will delete it from whatever class.

```
\lstset{
    morekeywords=[4]{bar},
    morekeywords=[3]{bar},
    morekeywords=[2]{bar},
    morekeywords=[1]{bar}
}
\lstinline{bar} % [4] wins; [3][2][1] deleted automatically
\lstset{
    deletekeywords=[3]{bar}, % nothing to delete
    deletekeywords=[2]{bar}  % nothing to delete
}
\lstinline{bar} % delete all styling whatsoever
```

## Test Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\lstset{
    basicstyle={\ttfamily\Huge[x]},
    keywordstyle={[1]\Huge[1]\color{blue}},
    keywordstyle={[2]\Huge[2]\color{red}},
    keywordstyle={[3]\Huge[3]\color{green}},
    keywordstyle={[4]\Huge[4]\color{yellow}}
}





\lstset{
    morekeywords=[4]{foo},
    morekeywords=[3]{foo},
    morekeywords=[2]{foo},
    morekeywords=[1]{foo}
}
\lstset{
    deletekeywords=[4]{foo}, % [4] deleted
    deletekeywords=[2]{foo}  % [2] deleted
}
\lstinline{foo} % [3] wins; [1] deleted automatically





\lstset{
    morekeywords=[4]{bar},
    morekeywords=[3]{bar},
    morekeywords=[2]{bar},
    morekeywords=[1]{bar}
}
\lstinline{bar} % [4] wins; [3][2][1] deleted automatically
\lstset{
    deletekeywords=[3]{bar}, % nothing to delete
    deletekeywords=[2]{bar}  % nothing to delete
}
\lstinline{bar} % delete all styling whatsoever





\end{document}
```

## True Story

The deeper answer is that whenever you enter `lstlisting` or `\lstinline` [listings](/questions/tagged/listings) will create a macro called `\lstk@bar` that memorize the style of `bar` should be, according to the class assignment.

And then when you try to delete `bar` from a specific class, although [listings](/questions/tagged/listings) does remembers the class a keyword is assigned to, it does not utilize this information. Instead, it deletes the styling macro `\lstk@bar`.

## Test Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabto}
\NumTabs{3}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\ttfamily
\def\@nametrace#1 {%
    \textbackslash#1\tab\expandafter\meaning\csname#1\endcsname
}
\def\traceall{
    \hrule height4pt\noindent
    \@nametrace lstk@foo           \\
    \@nametrace lstk@bar           %\\
%   \@nametrace lst@keywords@data  
    \hrule\noindent
%   \@nametrace lst@keywords@list  \\
    \@nametrace lst@keywords       \\
%   \@nametrace lst@keywords@also  \\
%   \@nametrace lst@gkeywords@list \\
    \@nametrace lst@gkeywords      %\\
%   \@nametrace lst@gkeywords@sty  \\
%   \@nametrace lst@keywordstyle   \\
    \hrule\noindent
%   \@nametrace lst@keywords2@list  \\
    \@nametrace lst@keywords2       \\
%   \@nametrace lst@keywords2@also  \\
%   \@nametrace lst@gkeywords2@list \\
    \@nametrace lst@gkeywords2      %\\
%   \@nametrace lst@gkeywords2@sty  \\
%   \@nametrace lst@keywordstyle2  
    \hrule\noindent
%   \@nametrace lst@keywords3@list  \\
    \@nametrace lst@keywords3       \\
%   \@nametrace lst@keywords3@also  \\
%   \@nametrace lst@gkeywords3@list \\
    \@nametrace lst@gkeywords3      %\\
%   \@nametrace lst@gkeywords3@sty  \\
%   \@nametrace lst@keywordstyle3   
    \hrule\noindent
%   \@nametrace lst@keywords4@list  \\
    \@nametrace lst@keywords4       \\
%   \@nametrace lst@keywords4@also  \\
%   \@nametrace lst@gkeywords4@list \\
    \@nametrace lst@gkeywords4      %\\
%   \@nametrace lst@gkeywords4@sty  \\
%   \@nametrace lst@keywordstyle4   
    \hrule height4pt
}

\lstset{
    basicstyle={\ttfamily\Huge[x]},
    keywordstyle={[1]\Huge[1]\color{blue}},
    keywordstyle={[2]\Huge[2]\color{red}},
    keywordstyle={[3]\Huge[3]\color{green}},
    keywordstyle={[4]\Huge[4]\color{yellow}}
}

add foo to four classes
\lstset{
    morekeywords=[4]{foo},
    morekeywords=[3]{foo},
    morekeywords=[2]{foo},
    morekeywords=[1]{foo}
}
\traceall
and delete from some classes
\lstset{
    deletekeywords=[4]{foo},
    deletekeywords=[2]{foo},
}
\traceall
\lstinline{foo}
\traceall

\clearpage

add bar to four classes
\lstset{
    morekeywords=[4]{bar},
    morekeywords=[3]{bar},
    morekeywords=[2]{bar},
    morekeywords=[1]{bar}
}
\traceall
\lstinline{bar}
\traceall
delete bar from some classes
\lstset{
    deletekeywords=[4]{bar},
    deletekeywords=[2]{bar}
}
\traceall
\lstinline{bar}
\traceall

\clearpage

firstly, delete
\lstset{
    deletekeywords=[3]{bar}
}
and then add
\lstset{
    morekeywords=[4]{bar},
    morekeywords=[3]{bar},
    morekeywords=[2]{bar},
    morekeywords=[1]{bar}
}
and then delete
\lstset{
    deletekeywords=[4]{bar},
    deletekeywords=[2]{bar}
}
and then add
\lstset{
    morekeywords=[4]{bar}
}
\traceall
\lstinline{bar}
\traceall

\end{document}
```